# What's a word to describe people who blindly follow their government without question?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, pejorative-language, politics

I want to describe someone who fanatically follows one of the following:

- Governmental body
- Political party
- Country

Basically, someone who will agree with their government/party/country regardless of what actions/decisions they make.

I was thinking of words such as *zealot*, *follower*, etc..

The word most similar to what I want is slang: *sheep*.

example in a sentence:

> Elise constantly agrees with anything the liberal party says and does without having any personal opinions; she is but a sheep.

Comment: It does not seem very easy. With a negative connotation: brainwashed people / sheeps, robots, slaves, victims, members of the control system  ?  Although you may seem to be after to a word also implying some active involvement, rather than mere passivity.

Comment: Pam, that should be *sheep* not *sheeps* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sheep?q=sheep

Comment: The nearest I can get is with the slogans 'My country/party, right or wrong'. This gets across the illogicality/mental indolence/hypocrisy often involved.

Comment: "The imaginary perfect citizen"

Comment: Despite the popular perception of `sheep` as a slang form, [_Sheeple_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheeple) is in fact a valid term that the public can easily relate to while having a civil discussion.

Comment: For the Q, is it important that the [thing] being followed is political? In other words are you searching for a term that distinguishes between blindly following {government/religion/science/tradition/...} or is it enough for just any uncritical blind following?

Comment: Sheeple, in the US, is almost exclusively used by one side as a slur on the other side. It will not be perceived as part of a civil discussion in many contexts.

Comment: What could you hope for, better than 'yes men'? Can you Post three or four examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not a noun, the term **[knee-jerk](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/knee-jerk)** is often applied to the category descriptor to demonstrate blind allegiance

> (Of a person) responding in an automatic and unthinking way:
>   *knee-jerk radicals*

[ODO]

Possibly **[partisan](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/partisan)**

> a person who takes the part of or strongly supports one side, party, or person; often, specif., an unreasoning, emotional adherent

[Collins]

The term **[chauvinist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/chauvinist)** is also used to indicate fierce commitment to a cause or point of view

> A person displaying excessive or prejudiced loyalty or support for a particular cause, group, or gender: *what a male chauvinist that man is*

[ODO]

When coupled with an aggressive, often militaristic stand, the term **[jingoist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/jingoism#jingoism)** may be used

> Extreme patriotism, especially in the form of aggressive or warlike foreign policy.

[ODO]

Comment: Chauvinist, from what I've read, holds very specific definitions relating to gender and patriotism only (not a government party). However, partisan looks to be exactly the word I'm looking for.

Comment: compliant, con-formal, orthodox.

Answer (score 7):

[**Sheeple**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheeple) is an interesting portmanteau that is a widely accepted term. An equivalent synonym/doctrine is "[*conformist*.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conformist)"

> [*Sheeple*] is used to describe those who voluntarily acquiesce to a suggestion without critical analysis or research. <sub><sup>Wikipedia</sup></sub>

It often portrays criticism in the tendency of crowd thinking and hive mindset. Here is a neat (*perhaps very satirical*) [comic](http://xkcd.com/1013/) from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/about/) to consider:

[image: waking the sheeple! XKCD #1013]

Answer (score 4):

I think you have already answered in your question by yourself, - 'a blind follower.

Answer (score 3):

A [Yes-man](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yes-man) :

> a person who agrees with everything that is said ; especially :  one who endorses or supports without criticism every opinion or proposal of an associate or superior.

Extract from http://www.lemauricien.com/article/political-fiction-yes-man

> Elected in the same constituency as the Leader, the Yes Man is an expert in menial work. He started by carrying posters for a former banished young stud of the same faction. Despite being relegated to the sidelines, this has-been has managed to feed off the generosity of the party by aligning himself with another fervent patriot and organising PR coups where he gets to promote himself more than the real talents. However, let us not wander too far from our luminary presence.

Comment: Sounds kind of odd calling 'Elise' a yes-man, though

Answer (score 3):

If such a person is actually part of the state, then they're a *functionary* or (more strongly) *apparatchik*.  Allegorically, they are a *drone* or *myrmidon*, both words with connotations of insect colonies.

Otherwise they would be a *zealot*, *true believer*, or *partisan* who had *drunk the Kool-Aid* (referring to the use of poisoned Kool-Aid (Flavor-Ade) in the Jonestown cult mass suicide / murder).

Answer (score 2):

*Sheep*. Just like that animal that moves wherever its herder takes it, no questions asked.

Answer (score 1):

[Ideologue](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ideologue) is probably the word your looking for, since your specifically looking for a word that describes *blind allegiance* to ideological or political forces.

- an often blindly partisan advocate or adherent of a particular ideology

[Partisan](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partisan) also is a pretty good word for what your describing itself. Typically its used now by politicians or media organization to slander each-other though, so its true meaning has become muted over the years due to over use.

- a firm adherent to a party, faction, cause, or person especially : one exhibiting blind, prejudiced, and unreasoning allegiance political partisans who see only one side of the problem

[Sycophant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sycophant) is also a pretty good word to describe people like that if they have something to personally gain or lose.

- A person who attempts to gain advantage by flattering influential people or behaving in a servile manner.
- A tale-bearer or informer in general.
- A parasite; a mean flatterer; especially, a flatterer of tyrants and great men.

It also has a connotation of someone who is slanderer, accuser, calumniator, etc.

There are also words like: [Fanatic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fanatic), and [Zealot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zealot)

Comment: +1 for 'ideologue'. 'Partisan' has already been opted in the accepted answer. 'Sycophant' is used in a completely different way, because it is about pretense, I think.

Answer (score 1):

While it deals specifically with Communism, Apparatchik seems to qualify.

1. Member of the communist party.
2. Unquestioningly loyal subordinate.
3. Sometimes an administrative position.

Answer (score 0):

I would call such persons 'the immature'.
For 'errare humanum est' (evb. makes mistakes), and 'individualism' does count but we must not neglect the opposite (community; a man is 'zoon politokon' - a man shall be tolerant but watchful activist, too).

Answer (score 0):

Would 'assimilate' (as in conform) be an appropriate synonym for what you're trying to say? Assimilating culture, policies, the 'new agenda'...

Answer (score 0):

Servile

1. having or showing an excessive willingness to serve or please others.
   "he bowed his head in a servile manner"
   synonyms:   obsequious, sycophantic, excessively deferential, subservient, fawning, toadying, ingratiating, unctuous, oily, oleaginous, greasy, grovelling, cringing, toadyish, slavish, abject, craven, humble, Uriah Heepish, self-abasing; More
   antonyms:   bossy, assertive
2. of or characteristic of a slave or slaves.

Comment: Please attribute your answer if you're citing from somewhere.

Comment: There is nothing in the example to suggest servility.

Answer (score 0):

Fanatical minion would be the only term I could come up with to describe blind followers of a political or religious dogma. Sorry that it is actually two words. This is totally different from a minion fanatic which is someone obsessed with characters from the movie "Despicable me"

Comment: Hi, Boo. This eight-year-old question with an accepted answer is for a single word. Welcome to the site and please [take the tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

A ["statist"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statist) is an advocate of statism, which is, in turn, the allowance of control into the "the hands of a highly centralized government, often extending to government ownership of industry." Contrast with "anarchist."

Comment: You need to reread the OP's example.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are looking for a pejorative to describe a single member of a group, who blindly follow.  Lemming is sometimes used for this purpose.

Comment: You need to link to or give a reasonably authoritative example/source...